# iPad css3 animation flickers after keyboard use

Tags: javascript, ipad, css, cordova

I'm developing an app for the iPad using HTML5/CSS3. I'm not using any framework and am just using whatever is natively supported on the device. I have created some css3 animations to emulate the typical iOS sliding left or sliding right when navigating between screens. Here's an example of the slide left animation which is taking advantage of the iPad's CSS3 hardware acceleration: (the ipad is running 4.2).

```
/*************************************************
Slide Left
*************************************************/
.screen.slideleft{
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.screen.slideleft.outgoing{
 z-index: 50 !important;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideleft-outgoing;

}
.screen.slideleft.incoming{
 z-index: 100 !important;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideleft-incoming;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideleft-outgoing{
 from { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideleft-incoming{
 from { -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0); }
}
```

I also have this CSS which I've attempted to use to fix the flicker:

`.incoming,
.outgoing{
 display: block !important;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}`

This works great until the iPad keyboard is used. After which point all the animations flicker severely.

I've been looking for examples of an iPad HTML5 app that uses the keyboard and doesn't have flickers afterwards, but haven't turned up much. The jqTouch demos exhibit the same behavior on the iPad (although I know they were designed for the iPhone).

I've turned up a few posts/questions of similar questions but have never found a good answer.  I've been through http://css3animator.com/2010/12/fight-the-flicker-making-your-css3-animation-bomb-proof/ and the articles linked there but haven't had any success.

Any other suggestions?

**Update 1/13 @ 9am**

I've added this css and it helped a lot:

`.incoming *,
.outgoing *{
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* This helps with the flicker a lot. */
}`

The foreground elements don't seem to flicker anymore, but the backgrounds still do. Still looking for some help or helpful resources on Mobile Safari's memory handling tactics.

**Update 1/16 @ 11pm**

Increasing the z-index as suggested by anonymous. Didn't seem to make a difference.

**Update 1/17 @ 8:30am**

I've posted a demo of the problem [here](http://projects.mediabounds.com/demos/flickering_demo/).

The transitions between screens work great...until you tap/click inside one of the form fields. After the keyboard slides up and returns, all the transitions flicker. Go to the URL inside the iOS simulator or on an actual iPad to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm still looking for any helpful advice!

Comment: Starting a bounty for someone who can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, there really wasn't a fix for this issue. It seems like form elements in WebKit on the iPad cause problems with flickering.

My workaround was that on the onblur of each form element, I refreshed the page using hash tags to ensure it refreshed to the exact same state. It still caused a "flicker" while it was refreshing, but it did keep the screen from flickering throughout the rest of the app.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd share my experience.

I've been having issues with outrageous flickering (on css3 animations) on the iPad (as well as the iPhone, but in that case only in portrait view). I was able to completely resolve all of the flickering issues by setting :

```
-webkit-perspective: 0;
```

On the elements being animated. I'm not sure why this works, but it does (tested on iOS 4.2+, both iPad (1 and 2) and iPhone 4).

Update: I've just become aware of an issue with Chrome when setting the value of that attribute to 1.  It works just fine when it's 0, so I've updated the above appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your source, the translate3d(0,0,0) isn't applied until the transition starts?

Try

```
.screen{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

or

```
.screen *, .screen{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

The flicker is probably the hardware acceleration kicking in (it currently only works on 3d translated elements).

Comment: I originally had it as only translateX instead of translate3d; I changed to translate3d to enable hardware acceleration, but either way, it flickers. Only after using the keyboard, however—works fine before the keyboard.

Comment: Interestingly enough, your first suggestion .screen{ -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); } DOES improve the flicker on the outgoing screen. The second suggestion made it worse - I suspect because of how much memory it was taking to have every element -webkit-transform: translate3d.

Comment: Good, is it perfect now or still need some tweaky?

Comment: If it's perfect you might try `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` on outgoing and `-webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);` on incoming.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but i was able to reduce the flicker to almost unnoticeable by applying the fix described here and here:

http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=301

https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/issues/issue/130

Basically set the z-index of the page you a are moving out to -1 and after the transistion back to 1

Comment: I tried changing z-index for .outgoing to -1 on both the slide left and slide right but it didn't fix (or even reduce) the flicker in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a dinosaur old question, but there is a solution for this issue and it is quite lightweight and very simple.

```
document.getElementById('clicked_input').addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
},false);
```

When i was tackling this issue too, I thought I tried everything - eventually the only thing that helped, was to create a modal window (position: absolute) outside of the app's container div, and also set the app's container div to display:false; when the keyboard was coming up. While it worked it was ugly, I tested everything to see what caused the event and it seemed that when the 'focus event' bubbled up, every 3d transform gets messed up (in flickering and performance).

Preventing the event of bubbling solved this issue completely - quite mind boggling that such a hated bug had such a simple solution?

Comment: That's a really fascinating idea--I'll keep this in the back of my mind to try next time (of course, with iOS5, who knows what'll change with WebKit).

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to like me saying this, but JavaScript may be the answer you're looking for. I fear that when you bring the keyboard up, the process of rendering the HTML loses priority. With a continually updating script, like a `setInterval` loop, the iPad will have no choice but to render as planned. Explicit code requires no hacks.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you're getting at-but in this case, I'm not using any sort of setInterval or setTimeout—I'm relying entirely on CSS transforms for animations. These transitions are hardware accelerated on the iPad. The only JavaScript that occurs anywhere near the flickering is simply adding a class or two.

Comment: And for clarity's sake, the flickering occurs even long after the keyboard has returned.

Comment: What I was saying was that maybe the problem is that you weren't using JavaScript. CSS is left to render asynchronously by the browser, which allows a large window of error. In your case, Safari has conflicting events that cause the flickering, and though there might be a slight performance hit, you would eliminate the flickering if you controlled the menus/widgets/sliders or whatever you call them with JavaScript.

Comment: I was under the impression that the CSS3 transforms allow the browser to repaint without any need for rendering; because of that, CSS transforms would always give better results than anything that used JavaScript since those would require rendering. What would the "conflicting events" be even after the keyboard has long since disappeared? I'll give the JavaScript a shot and see if it helps at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood this whole thing. I thought this was about CSS animations. This is CSS3D? What you have is a zbuffering issue. I'd say increase the size of the units you're using. Make everything further apart.

Comment: I changed the incoming z-index to 100 instead of 50 (I updated the CSS above) but it didn't make a difference. I'll post an example tomorrow so people can actually see what's happening.

Comment: The z-index value shouldn't be an issue. I'm worried about the perspective transforms of the element. Do you understand 3D math?

Comment: I do understand 3D math. If I understand what you're suggesting correctly, I did mess with the z value of the 3d transformation, but it still had the same issue. I've posted a demo of the problem here: http://projects.mediabounds.com/demos/flickering_demo/ The problem occurs even on the simulator, so if you have the iOS simulator, you can see exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: No, I don't have an iOS simulator, I'm sorry. From here, everything seems to be in order.

Comment: Well I appreciate your input up to this point! I'll keep trying to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ben, you should probably set transforms on the classes themselves as well:

```
/*************************************************
Slide Left
*************************************************/
.screen.slideleft{
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.screen.slideleft.outgoing{
 z-index: 50 !important;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideleft-outgoing;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}
.screen.slideleft.incoming{
 z-index: 100 !important;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideleft-incoming;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideleft-outgoing{
 from { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideleft-incoming{
 from { -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0); }
 to { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
}
```

If that doesn't work, I'd be curious to test if only translating the X with `translateX(-100%)` fixes the problem. (Not necessarily a fix, because you don't have hardware acceleration without 3D transforms, but would help narrow down the problem.)

Comment: I actually originally had it as translateX and changed it to translate3d to enable hardware acceleration. It hasn't made a difference either way. I've tried adding translate3d's and moving others with only minor success. See my comment on Ben's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been having the same problem and tried all sorts of complicated fixes. In the end I found the issue was down to the default styling on the input. I fixed my problem by adding the css `input{outline:none}`. It's prob just on the focus state so `input:focus{outline:none;}` should work.